# Tracking total execution time Google apps script for an account

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps script has the limitation of 6 hours triggered scripts per day per account.

I recently started getting the alerts `Service using too much computer time for one day`.

> Is there a way track the total time of triggered scripts by project?

I found so far this [post](https://medium.com/@dkodr/how-to-keep-track-of-google-apps-scripts-total-execution-time-c46e9d1dfdef) , but then I'd need to lookup all of my 50 projects.

Thank you

Comment: From the referred article "This helped me find the most problematic projects and work on their speed and efficiency". Did you try the script on the referred article?

Comment: Could use [console.time() & .timeEnd()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#time(String)) with [Stackdriver logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging), you would have find your triggers and add the timers, then query the data you want - kinda sounds like the linked post, but you can do more with Stackdriver logging

Comment: The issue is that I have a bunch of computer time heavy projects. I know it. I do not see how to optimize them. But adding more code I'll slow it down by frictions of a second. Since I have a number of every minute tiggers that check if there was an activation. It adds up. As of now an every minute trigger uses 0.25 s per minute. I thought there is a central place to check the project/account activity like in GCP to see when I need to move triggers to another account or alike.

Comment: Try [Automated Access to Google Analytics Data in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script). When you automate your script, you may retrieve the data which includes `timer`. See if it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the total execution time of functions executed by the time-driven trigger.

If my understanding is correct, how about this method? By the update of Apps Script API, the method for retrieving the process of project was added. I thought that this can be used for above situation.

### Flow

1. Retrieve the process list of functions by the method of "processes.list" in Apps Script API.

   - At that time, set the period for retrieving the total execution time using `startTime` and `endTime`.
   - As the filter, "TIME_DRIVEN" of the process type is used. By this, the process list of functions executed by the time-driven trigger can be retrieved.
2. Sum the duration time of each function.

### Sample script:

#### Preparation:

Before you use this script, please enable Apps Script API as follows.

Enable Apps Script API at API console:

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click "Explore and enable APIs".
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "apps script". And click Apps Script API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If this API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

Add scopes:

Please add the following scopes to the Manifest file (`appsscript.json`).

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.processes"
]
```

- On script editor

  - View -> Show manifest file
  - Add the above property.

#### Script:

Before you run this script, please set `startTime` and `endTime`. This is the period for calculating the total time. In this sample script, the total time from `2019-02-07T00:00:00.000Z` to `2019-02-08T00:00:00.000Z` is calculated.

```
function myFunction() {
  var startTime = "2019-02-07T00:00:00.000Z"; // Please set this.
  var endTime = "2019-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"; // Please set this.

  var params = {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var data = [];
  var nextPageToken = "";
  var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/processes";
  do {
    var query = "?fields=%2a" +
    "&pageToken=" + encodeURIComponent(nextPageToken) +
    "&userProcessFilter.types=TIME_DRIVEN" +
    "&userProcessFilter.startTime=" + encodeURIComponent(startTime) +   
    "&userProcessFilter.endTime=" + encodeURIComponent(endTime);
    var res = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + query, params).getContentText());
    Array.prototype.push.apply(data, res.processes);
    nextPageToken = res.nextPageToken || "";
  } while (nextPageToken);
  var result = data.reduce(function(obj, e) {
    obj[e.functionName] = obj[e.functionName] ? obj[e.functionName] + Number(e.duration.replace("s", "")) : Number(e.duration.replace("s", ""));
    return obj;
  }, {});
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

#### Result:

As a sample situation, when 2 functions of `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` are run by the time-driven trigger, this script returns the following result. The result means that for `startTime` and `endTime`, the total execution times of `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` are 123.456 s and 12.345 s, respectively.

```
{
  "myFunction1": 123.456,
  "myFunction2": 12.345
}
```

### Note:

- About `startTime` and `endTime`, a timestamp in RFC3339 UTC "Zulu" format, accurate to nanoseconds. Example: `2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z`. This is from the official document.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it to your situation.

### References:

- [processes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes)
- [Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests)

If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Ilja Also I created this method as a GAS library. https://github.com/tanaikech/ProcessApp If this is useful for your situation, I'm glad.

Comment: @Ilja Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. If no data is returned, it indicates that there are no data in the period you inputted. Also it seems that the process list cannot saved much old data. So if you test it, please input the period of recent dates. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand the detail information about your current situation and script from ``it did not return anything to me``. So can you provide your detail information for correctly understanding it? If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of your issue.

Comment: I ran it and it just runs for minutes and minutes... In the execution transcript, it seems that something runs but I cannot see if results are created. Maybe it's because there are so many triggers? I'll try to filter the request

Comment: I tried again, with setting up a completely new sheet, using only the library and it worked! It ran for some 20 minutes but returned a result of some 200 minutes total runtime. Thanks

Comment: @Ilja Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.