# Measure my current usage consumption on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, limit, quota

I have a google app script that execute the following actions:
Read a incoming webhook, write some information on a google spreadsheet, update a google contact and generates several outbound webhooks.
It takes aproximately 5 seconds to execute the whole script.

I would like to know how much times per day I can execute this script. I have seen the following web page but I am not sure in which feature my actions might fit, since there is no description of what those each feature means.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Also I check in the google app script dashboard in hope I could find the current usage of my app script, but I only found that my script is execute 500 times per day for an average of 5 seconds per execution. In the future I am going to need to execute this app script more times, but I will like to know which is limit.

¿Where can I find my current app script consumption and which are the quotas for the features I am currently using?

Comment: You cannot check current quotas filled percent, you will get an error only when you actually hit some quota, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages

Comment: The most you should have to worry about is total trigger runtime of 90 minutes. 500 calls @5s is around 41 minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definetely check that quota

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Google Apps Script has a [quota page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) that shows execution limits on various services.

Please note that you can get quota exception messages if you go near these limits but not go over them entirely.

Since you mentioned that you may need to execute your script more than 500 times a day, you might want to start optimizing your functions to take less time. You can start searching for resources on how to do this, for example in this post: [Tracking total execution time Google apps script for an account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883691/tracking-total-execution-time-google-apps-script-for-an-account)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am no sure that I understand what each feature of the quota page means. For example, does my inbound and outbound webhooks enter under the "URL Fetch calls" feature? Does that mean I can trigger 20,000 webhooks per day?

Comment: Technically yes, but you may experience quota errors at slightly less than the indicated limit. Safe limits are half of the indicated ones.